# Update 'Profile Page' adding entries to mySQL database form PHP form?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have created a simple login and registration project.

The user is then presented with their 'Profile Page'. I want them to be able to click an 'edit' button and type information into fields that were not present during registration. I can get the script to add a 'bio' to the database but it creates a new record, How can I add this bio info to a particular members record?

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['Email'])){
header("Location: login.php");
}   
?>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("HIDDEN");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("HIDDEN", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO members (Bio)
VALUES
('$_POST[Bio]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>

<form action="edit.php" method="post">
Bio: <input type="text" name="Bio">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `bio` column is in the same table, then you need to perform an `UPDATE` statement, not another `INSERT` statement. You also need to know the user’s ID.

```
UPDATE `members` SET `bio` = ?
```

Also, don’t use `$_POST` variables directly in an SQL statement. You’re leaving your site vulnerable to SQL injection vulnerabilities then. Use something like PDO to prepare statements and then execute them with bound parameters. An example, where `$db` in an instance of [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
$sql = "UPDATE `members` SET `bio` = :bio WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1";

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(':bio', $bio);
$statement->bindParam(':id', $user_id);
$statement->execute();
```

You’ll need to assign the `$bio` and `$user_id` variables.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I've been advised of PDO before but am just wanting to finish this project first as it's for enhancing my very weak php skills. The Update makes sense, however, how can I dynamically fill the users id '?' as they will already be logged in? Would it be $_SESSION['id']?

Comment: Use this to verbose variable values: `echo '<pre>'.print_r( $_SESSION, true ).'</pre>'` (to see what's in $_SESSION in this sample).

Comment: If you’re storing the user ID in a session, then yes, you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['Email'])){
header("Location: login.php");
}   
?>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
$con = mysql_connect("HIDDEN");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("HIDDEN", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO members(Bio) VALUES ('".$_POST['Bio']."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
}
?>

<form action="edit.php" method="post">
Bio: <input type="text" name="Bio">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```